# $\mathfrak a$-adic Completion of a Ring is Flat

Tags: commutative-algebra, flatness

Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring and $\mathfrak a \subset A$ an ideal of $A$. Denote by $\hat{A_{\mathfrak a}}:= \varprojlim_n A/\mathfrak a^n$ the $\mathfrak a$-adic completion of $A$ wrt $\mathfrak a$.

Why and how to see that $\hat{A_{\mathfrak a}}$ is a ***flat*** $A$-module?

Could anybody give sketch for the proof?

My considerations: up to now I know that firstly $\mathfrak a$ is finitely generated.

Remark: As @Max mentioned below one cannot expect that the canonical map $A \to \hat{A_{\mathfrak a}}$ is injective  (Krull's intersection thm only works for local Noetherians).

Comment: Krull's intersection theorem is for local rings; there are examples where $A\to \widehat{A}_a$ is not injective, even for noetherian rings.

Comment: @Max: thank you for this important remark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You can find a solution to this problem in the following document of ***Conrad*** [Artin–Rees and completions.](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/210BPage/handouts/completion.pdf) In particular it is the **Corollary 3.2**.
- Also, in the book of ***Qing Liu - Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*** you can find a proof in the **Theorem 3.15.** I love how Liu wrote the review of commutative algebra in his book and I recommend you to read it.

Here a snap of the proof taken from Liu's book.

[image: Theorem 3.15 - From Liu's book.]

The ***Corollary 3.14*** that Liu is referring to is the well-known result:

[image: Corollary 3.14 - From Liu's book.]

- Here the approach to this theorem in ***Matsumura: Commutative Ring Theory, Chapter 3***.

The main theorem is ***Theorem 8.8:***

[image: Theorem 8.8 - From Matsumura's book.]

The theorems that Matsumura is referring to are:

***Theorem 7.7:***

[image: Theorem 7.7 - From Matsumura's book.]

***Theorem 8.1:***

[image: Theorem 8.1 - From Matsumura's book.]

***Theorem 8.6:***

[image: Theorem 8.6 - From Matsumura's book.]

*Note* The notation of the above theorem is: $A$ a noetherian ring, $M$ a finite $A$-module, $N \subset M$ a submodule, and $I$ an ideal of $A$.

I hope this helps you. If you don't understand the references I gave you, don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: I have two questions: 

1) the "canonically" morphism $M \otimes_A \hat{A} \to \hat{M}$ from 3.14 is given concretely via $m \otimes (\alpha_n)_n \mapsto (m \cdot\alpha_n)_n$? As well as $\hat{J} \to \hat{A}$ componentswise $J/JI^n \to A/I^n, \iota + JI^n \mapsto + \iota +I^n$ in each $n$?

Comment: 2) Another point regarding proof of thm 3.15 is why is $\beta_m \in I^nJ$?

Comment: 1) The mapping $M\otimes_A \hat{A} \rightarrow \hat{M}$ is by definition called canonical (Bourbaki, Commutative Algebra, pg. 202) It's is defined as you said, by the universal property of tensor products applied to the map $M \times \hat{A} \rightarrow \hat{M} \ : \ (m,(a_n)_n) \mapsto (a_n \cdot m)_n.$ Yes, the map $\hat{J} \rightarrow \hat{A}$ is defined this way. Note that it's the map induced by the $A$-linear map $J \rightarrowtail A,$ the injection of $J$ in $A.$

Comment: 2) If $\beta_m + I^{m}J = \alpha_m + I^{m}J$ then $\beta_m - \alpha_m \in I^{m}J$ and $I^{m}J \subset I^{m} \cap J \subset I^{m}.$ Furthermore, since $\alpha$ is in the kernel, we get that $\alpha_m \in I^{m}$ so $\beta_m \in I^{m}$ and $\beta_m \in I^{m} \cap J \subset I^{n}J.$

Comment: ah ok and $\alpha_n$ MUST be image of $\beta_m$ since all elements $ (\alpha_n)_n \in \hat{J}$ are compatible in the sense that $\alpha_m + JI^m \mapsto \alpha_n + JI^n$ for $m \ge n$ by definition. So the image of $\beta_m$ in $J/JI^n$ doesn't have "another choice" as to be $\alpha_n$?

Comment: Yes, you got it! If you want to see another approach (distinct from the above) to this theorem you could read the book of ***Matsumura: Commutative Ring Theory, Chapter 3.*** It's a bit hard to read but when you understand this book you will see trivially a lot of stuff from Commutative Algebra.

Answer (score 0):

The Stacks project has a proof, https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06LE, considering the direct sum over a one element index set.